# How to use Go Router refreshListenable parameter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to know how to use the refreshListenable parameter of the Go router package, but I can't find the documentation and I don't know if I should use Streams or a ValueNotifier?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116651) on the Flutter repo for more information. It sounds like long-term, the Flutter team will likely remove this property from GoRouter.